# problem in a function that removes only the last element in a list of list

Tags: c

so I created a function that delete a structure on a linked list which is on an other linked list. We have the principal structure "abonnes" which contains a pointer to another structure "liste_fav", liste_fav represent the list of favorite numbers of a subscriber, and "abonnes" represent every subscriber. The problem is that this function delete only the last structure of our linked list. Can you help me please?
the structures are :

```
 typedef struct abonnes // the principal structure of subscribers
{
    signed char  num_c[20];
    signed  char operateur [20];
    signed char profil[20];
    int credit;
    liste_fav liste;
    struct abonnes *adr;
}abonnes; 

typedef struct liste_fav// the list which is on the principal list.
{
       signed char numf[20];
       struct liste_fav *suiv;

}liste_fav;
```

this is the function :

```
    void supp_fav(abonnes *p ,signed char * num)// we give to our function the number to delete on the list, and we have to find the structure which contains this number to delete.
{
   liste_fav *q,*ty,*ee;
    q = acces_num(p,num,&ty);// this function gives the pointer which point in the structure where is the number , it works perfectly.
    ee=&(p->liste);// we initialize ee on the head of the liste_fav
    if (q==NULL)
        printf("le numero n'existe pas ");// if the numero doesn't exist in our liste_fav
    else
    {
        if ( ee == q)//if the num is on the head of the liste_fav
        {
            ee = suivant_fav_propre(ee);// the definition is below
        }
        else
        {
            aff_adr_fav_propre(ty,suivant_fav_propre(q));// the definition is below
            liberer_fav_propre(q);// the definition is below 
        }

    }

}
```

this is the definition of the precedent sub-functions:

```
    void aff_adr_fav_propre (liste_fav*s , liste_fav *q)
{
    s -> suiv = q;
}



liste_fav *suivant_fav_propre(liste_fav *p)
{
    return (p->suiv);
}


void liberer_fav_propre ( liste_fav *p)
{
    free(p -> suiv);
}
```

Comment: Why does `abonnes` contain the member `liste_fav liste;` instead of `liste_fav *liste;`? Does the `liste` member contain a "dummy" element containing no real data? If it contains real data, how would you free the element, given that it is embedded within `abonnes`? Also, does `ty` point to the element before the one to be freed?

Comment: The line `ee = suivant_fav_propre(ee);` does not change the data structure, and the function just returns after this line, so it seems a bit pointless.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines:

```
            aff_adr_fav_propre(ty,suivant_fav_propre(q));// the definition is below
            liberer_fav_propre(q);// the definition is below
```

are equivalent to:

```
            ty->suiv = q->suiv;
            free(q->suiv);
```

So `ty->suiv` will be pointing to a block that has just been freed. I'm not entirely sure how the code is supposed to work, but that looks wrong!